# Sorting specific values depending on the Boolean

Tags: php, mysql

What I want to do is to sort out `ID` using php that is Reserved( the value of Reserved is 'true' or '1'. Meaning of sort out is, I only want print `ID` value of the rows with value '1' on the Reserved column.

The value of Reserved and Available is in Boolean.

So, if the database shows following:

```
ID    | Reserved  |  Available
A1    |   0       |    0
A2    |   1       |    0
A3    |   1       |    0
A4    |   0       |    0
```

with the function, I want to get `A2` and `A3` as the result.

I have the following codes now:

```html
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM SeatsStatus");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";}
?>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "sort out ID"? Have you written any code? If so, please add it to your question.

Comment: Change your query to this one: `SELECT ID FROM SeatsStatus WHERE Reserved = 1`. It will return only ID where reserved is true.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your query to this one:

```
SELECT ID FROM SeatsStatus WHERE Reserved = 1
```

It will return only IDs where Reserved has a value of 1.